# quadratic equation in n variables

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

I have a quadratic equation in the form:

$a_{0}^{2}+a_{1}^{2}t^{2}+a_{2}^{2}t^{4}+...+a_{n}^{2}t^{2n}+2(a_0a_1t+a_0a_2t^2+...+a_0a_nt^n+...+a_na_{n-1}t^{2n-1})=\phi(c)$.

All $a_i$ are algebraically independent. I need to solve this equation at 2 different points for $t= \alpha, \beta  $.

Now can I write this equation in terms of  new variable $c_i$

$ \text {where $c_i $is the coefficient of }t^i$ as $c_i:=\sum_{j=0}^{i}a_ja_{i-j}$ and solve?

Thank you!

Comment: done!. thank you